# Facebook for Developers page issue: There are no apps to display here. Would you like to create a new app?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I am using the Facebook SDK for Unity and I am unable to successfully log in with the example scenes.  There is a "Find Access Token" button and when I press it, I am sent to this page:

[image]

It states: There are no apps to display here. Would you like to create a new app?

I've tried creating new apps, but it doesn't help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Name and App Id need to be configured correctly on the FacebookSettings asset file.  This file is in the Assets\Facebook\Resources\ folder.  The default values will not work correctly for getting tokens.

[image]

You must use the App Name and App Id from the newly created app on the Facebook for Developers page.

After setting the App Name and App Id correctly, the page instead looks like this:
[image]